# What do I install into a given install prefix

Tags: filesystems, software-installation, directory-structure, make, gnu-make

Which directories should I expect to have in an install prefix when I'm writing makefiles? I've noticed that in the common prefix `/usr`, there is no `/etc`, yet there is an `/include` dir, which isn't in the root directory. Which paths are hard-coded such as `/etc` and `/var` maybe and which directories lie in a prefix? As far as I can see `/bin` and `/lib` are standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the FHS (Filesystem Heirarchy Standard) for details:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard and http://www.pathname.com/fhs/

Comment: So is etc/ and var/ always only in root and is include/ always only in usr/. Does everything else come under the prefix?

Comment: It can, many common services when built locally will install to `/usr/local/<application>` beneath which they may create `./bin`, `./lib`, `./log` and more.  Some apps / services can be configured (by `autoconf` / `automake`) to install to the 'real' `/bin`, `/lib` etc...

Comment: Is etc relative?

Comment: In some cases, but not necessarily all.  Typically, `./bin` is user binaries, `./sbin` system binaries, `./lib` shared libraries, `/var` for logfiles, lockfiles and other 'runtime' files, `/etc` for configuration files.  `automake` / `autoconf` allow the user to specify paths for each of these, so a user may choose to use `./etc` rather than `/etc` for a locally installed package if they wish.